# Windows 8 OEM on Dell Desktop, Installed Ubuntu on partition, reboot to see only 'grub >'

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a dell desktop with windows 8 installed (OEM). I shrunk the windows 8 partition to 200gb and installed ubuntu on the remaining 1.8 tb of space.

During installation, I picked /dev/sda6 as my `/` partition and I chose the default `/dev/sda` to install the boot loader.

When I restarted my computer, I end up in the grub menu. All I see now is `grub >`.

I tried installing the boot-repair tool available on yannubuntu, and I am unable to resolve anything on my own.

[This is the paste generated by the tool](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6367333/)

Can someone please teach me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not hit "Recommeded Repair"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Boot Repair didn't do anything helpful, try the following:

1. [Disable Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) Unfortunately, the details of how to do this vary from one computer to another.
2. Download the CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
3. Create a CD-R or USB flash drive of rEFInd.
4. Boot from the rEFInd medium you've created. With any luck, you'll see the rEFInd menu with options for Windows and Linux. (You'll probably see multiple options for each OS.)
5. Test these options. With any luck, at least one Windows option and at least one Linux option will work. Some of these options will bring you to your non-functional `grub>` prompt, though.
6. If you can boot both Linux and Windows, install the rEFInd Debian package in Linux.

At this point, rEFInd should come up as your primary boot loader. The trick is then to clean up the unwanted boot entries, which you can do by deleting `.efi` files from the `/boot/efi/EFI` directory tree in Linux and/or by using the `dont_scan_files` and `dont_scan_dirs` options in `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf`. Be careful what you delete, though. (I recommend making a backup of the entire `/boot/efi` directory tree; that way you can restore it if you make a mistake.)